# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/arjun/iKy/backend/factories/apikeys.json' in parrot os

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to start a app.py file. while trying to run the i am getting "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:". i'm not sure where i am blocked.

I'm trying to run iKy program. and the permission levels are also changed. I'm using parrot OS.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
from factories.application import create_application
File "/home/arjun/iKy/backend/factories/application.py", line 5, in
<module>
from api import home
File "/home/arjun/iKy/backend/api.py", line 3, in <module>
from factories._celery import create_celery
File "/home/arjun/iKy/backend/factories/_celery.py", line 2, in
<module>
from celery import Celery
ImportError: No module named celery
```

i have attached the image here.pls help me to fix this issue.

Comment: please post the error message as text and not as image. and: the error message in the image is very different from the one in the title of your question... please try to make your question more consistent...